# Stopping the Spring Boot application after receiving one event from Kafka Topic

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, maven, spring-kafka

We are encountering some issues while trying to stop the Kafka Consumer and the Java Application after receiving one event from the Kafka Topic (Spring Boot application). We are trying to stop the application after each event received.

We used the @Async annotation and we are trying to stop the current thread and then the consumer and the Java application .. Currently, the application tries to stop the current thread, but somehow it also executes all the other threads that contain the other events. What happens in the end is - instead of only executing the first thread with the first event, it executes all the threads and after that it stops the consumer.
After the first event, we can see the log that says "Event processed - Stopping the app", but it continues to execute all the other threads. We are currently using an external sdk that offers the Kafka functionality, so there are some limitations.

```java
@Async
public void async () {
    log.info("Event processed, stopping the app");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        consumerController.stopConsumer();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Thread interruped. App stopped." + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images, but use the code tags to properly include the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it was from the VM, I wrote it down manually. Thanks for the advice!